# Raw Engine Noise

Tags: engine, chevrolet, noise, cobalt

I have a cobalt LS 2006 model at about 100,600 miles. Around December of 2016 my cars engine start up sound became more raw. In response i had the oil and coolant changed out, but it did not revert back to its normal start up sound. So, i bough some belt dressing in the hopes that it was a 2 dollar fix. After using the dressing for a week and a half, i have deduced it is not the belt causing the noise. So, i have attached the sound file, what could this be?

https://soundcloud.com/amanda-archer-940279718

Ill add a better sound sample if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult to know what you are referring to in that sound clip. It sounds normal to me. The term "raw" doesn't really give detail to what you are describing to us. What part of the "start up" sound is not normal to you? Is there a new ticking, whirling, screeching, squealing, thumping?

Comment: Normally the engine has a more muffled startup. I will say that the raw engine noise only lasts thirty seconds to a minute and it quiets down. I'll record the normal sound after the initial start up and try and find a audio clip of a normal startup sound for a cobalt.

Comment: After googling I think I narrowed the sound down to the timing belt or it's tensioner pulley.

Comment: Did this start suddenly, or gradually become noticeable over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took it in. Needed a new timing belt.

Answer (score 1):

On newer cars, the timing chain tensioner works off of oil pressure.  When your car sits, the oil pressure bleeds off. So when you start it, you hear the timing chain slapping. It a common problem especially with hondas and "entry level" chevys

Answer (score 0):

be very cautious with it I owned the same car and replaced timing belt changed the oil fluids with every known tuneup and it still blew up on me after 170k miles

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.